# Install my software on another PC with local DB - not working

Tags: vb.net

I have publish my software but when I install it on another PC I recieve the message  `Sql Network interfaces error 50 or 52 ..`

When the database was localdb, I didn't have to install the sql server.

Can anyone explain it to me, please.

My db code looks like this:

```
configuration>
<configSections>
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Real_Programi.My.MySettings.REALDATAConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\REALDATA.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
</startup>
```

Comment: you have to install localdb on the target machine, if it's not there already. If the machine doesn't have Visual Studio or SQL server (with the correct option selected) installed then it won't be there. It's not a standard Windows component, and nor is it a magical creature which just manifests itself. You have to add it to the machine yourself. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-2016-express-localdb

Comment: aha.  it means i have to add the local db manually ??
but why in other softwares i have published it doesnt ask me for sql server ? just for this ??

Comment: I don't know what you published or where you published it, but I would guess that either those applications didn't use localdb, or it was already installed on the machine. So yes, in this case you have to install it manually. Just download SQL Server (express edition will be fine if you don't have a license) and choose the localdb option during installation. That link I gave you explains everything you should need, or you can google for more detail.